# how to remove all comments in production branch

Tags: javascript, git, github, version-control, comments

I have two environments: main branch and production branch. The problem is that I have a lot of comments in every line of code and I want to remove them in the production branch. I tried cleaning the comments manually for production, but after I make some changes in the main branch and merge to production, all the comments are back. Is there any way to remove all the comments in the production branch?

Comment: You'd be better off having to keep the comments in version control and have a (post-)build process to strip them for production, because maintaining branches with/without comments would be an everlasting hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey if u are using babel cli u can remove comments by updating .babelrc config

```
{comments: false}
```

or u can pass it like this while building

```
"build": "babel ./index.js --out-dir ./dist/index.js --no-comments"
```

and if u want to use gulp

you can use gulp-strip-comments

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var strip = require('gulp-strip-comments');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('template.js')
    .pipe(strip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```